# PSQL timestamp - how to include microseconds?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I create an SQL timestamp from an ISO timestamp that includes microseconds? e.g. `select to_timestamp('2021-08-29T16:32:25.336239Z','yyyy-mm-ddThh24:mi:ss.usZ')` will result in `2021-08-29 16:32:25` - microseconds precision lost.

Comment: Your code works fine when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9a854aa3466bd03750635b469c26a9f8.

Comment: I tried in H2, maybe it didn't implement `to_timestamp` properly

Comment: . . It is actually probably just the way the timestamp is displayed.

Comment: With the accepted answer, H2 displays timestamp with ms precision, so I don't think this is about presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ISO timestamps directly:

```
select TIMESTAMP '2021-08-29T16:32:25.336239Z' as ts
```

The `TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.nnnnnn+offset'` is the standard ANSI SQL format, which PG supports, and they also support ISO8601 in addition to it, since the difference is minimal. When using as a parameter from a whatever language you're using, you don't use the `TIMESTAMP` keyword, because it will result in a syntax error.